# WP Error using wp_insert_term

Tags: php

I have attached my code below. This code previously worked, but has since stopped. I can't understand why the error code is throwing now. I've marked where the error is occuring using // *** ISSUE IS RIGHT HERE *** //

I have looked through plenty of resources on wp_insert_term but nothing explains why I am getting invalid taxonomy in return/wp error. Can anyone help with this?

```
$meta_input = array(
                'cstatus' => $cstatus,
                'price' => $price,
                'year' => $year,
                'miles' => $miles,
                'exterior' => $exterior,
                'interior' => $interior,
                'drive' => $drive,
                'transmission' => $transmission,
                'petrol' => $petrol,
                'engine' => $engine,
                'topcategory' => 'no',
                'featured' => 'no',
                'html' => 'no',
                'visitorcounter' => 'no',
                'showgooglemap' => 'no',
                'map_location' => 'Pensacola Florida',
                'map-log' => '-87.263980',
                'map-lat' => '30.495620',
                'map-country' => 'US',
                'map-address1' => '6200',
                'map-address2' => 'Pensacola Blvd',
                'map-address3' => 'Pensacola Florida',
                'map-zip' => '32505',
                'map-state' => 'FL',
            );

            $postarr = array(
                'ID' => $post_id,
                'post_content' => $post_content,
                'post_title' => $post_title,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_type' => 'listing_type',
                'post_author'=>32,
                'comment_status' => 'closed',
                'guid' => $guid,
                'meta_input' => $meta_input
            );
            $have_guids[$guid] = 1;

            $post_id = wp_insert_post($postarr);

            if($post_id > 0 && $new_post && $image_url)
            {
                Generate_Featured_Image($image_url, $post_id);

                $make_term_exists = get_term_by( 'name', $make, 'make', ARRAY_A );

                if($make_term_exists == false){
                    $make_new = wp_insert_term($make,'make');

                    if ( ! is_wp_error( $make_new ) )
                    { 
                        // Do Nothing;
                    }
                    else
                    { 
                        echo $make_new->get_error_message(); 
                    }
                    // *** ISSUE IS RIGHT HERE *** //
                    $make_id = $make_new['term_id'];
                }else{
                    $make_id = $make_term_exists['term_id'];
                }


                if($make_id > 0)
                {
                    wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, array($make_id), 'make' );
                }

                $model_term_exists = get_term_by( 'name', $model, 'model', ARRAY_A );
                if($model_term_exists == false){
                    $model_new = wp_insert_term($model, 'model');
                    $model_id = $model_new['term_id'] ;
                }else{
                    $model_id = $model_term_exists['term_id'];
                }
                if($model_id > 0)
                {
                    wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, array($model_id), 'model' );
                }
                $add_count++;
            }else if($post_id > 0){
                $update_count++;
            }
```

Comment: Depending on your code, check if wp_insert_term is not called before register_taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

Move the $make_new['term_id'] inside the block that runs when there is no error.

Do you have your WP_DEBUG on? What is the error message?